# Using Javascript, how can I target and alter the URL of an image with no ID or class?

Tags: javascript

How can I alter the  URL that is buried quite deep in div's and alter it's URL only when a class is present of a parent>parent>parent div.

Context: I'm trying to alter the logo image in a sticky header that alters its background colour when scrolled. When the altered state is active, one of the parent divs has a class called ".bt-active" added.

Something like this, the normal state code is:

```
<section class="bdt-sticky">
<div data-id="208ba95" class=" element  element-208ba95  logo  widget  widget-image" id=" logo" data-element_type="image.default">
    <div class=" widget-container">
        <div class=" image">
            <a href="https://site.uk/" data- open-lightbox=""><img src="logo-1.png" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" width="180" height="26"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the code when the sticky is active is:

```
<section class="bdt-sticky bdt-active">
<div data-id="208ba95" class=" element  element-208ba95  logo  widget  widget-image" id=" logo" data-element_type="image.default">
    <div class=" widget-container">
        <div class=" image">
            <a href="https://site.uk/" data- open-lightbox=""><img src="logo-1.png" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" width="180" height="26"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to alter the logo in the active state to be src="logo-2.png"

Comment: But...it *does* have a class. Several of them. ...?

Comment: use these class class="attachment-full size-full" which are already there in image tag

Comment: What is `data-<space>` ?

Comment: Ahh, yes, sorry - meant a specific class (or ID) that wont impact anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The `img` *does* have a class. A couple of them. If they're shared by other images you may not want to target, you just have to look at its ancestors to add more specificity via descendant and/or child combinators.

Using `document.querySelector` with any of these selectors would target that `img`, with increasing restrictiveness:

```
.attachment-full
.attachment-full.size-full
.image .attachment-full
.image .attachment-full.size-full
.image > .attachment-full.size-full
.image > .attachment-full
.widget-container .attachment-full
.widget-container .attachment-full.size-full
.widget-container .image .attachment-full
.widget-container .image .attachment-full.size-full
.widget-container > .image > .attachment-full.size-full
```

You get the idea. :-)

If you like, you can put `img` in front of `.attachment-full` to limit that to `img` elements.

You can also target the `src` attribute:

```
[src="logo-1.png"]
```

That can be combined with any of the above (example: `img[src="logo-1.png"].attachment-full`).

[Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Live Example:

```js
function check(selector) {
    console.log(selector + " => " + document.querySelector(selector) ? "found" : "not found");
}

check(".attachment-full");
check(".attachment-full.size-full");
check(".image .attachment-full");
check(".image .attachment-full.size-full");
check(".image > .attachment-full.size-full");
check(".image > .attachment-full");
check(".widget-container .attachment-full");
check(".widget-container .attachment-full.size-full");
check(".widget-container .image .attachment-full");
check(".widget-container .image .attachment-full.size-full");
check(".widget-container > .image > .attachment-full.size-full");
```

```html
<section class="bdt-sticky">
    <div data-id="208ba95" class=" element  element-208ba95  logo  widget  widget-image" id=" logo" data-element_type="image.default">
        <div class=" widget-container">
            <div class=" image">
                <a href="https://example.com/" data- open-lightbox=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150/0000FF/808080?text=Example" class="attachment-full size-full" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it the only image inside the active `section`? If so, you don't need to have an `id` or a `class` on the image itself.
Just point to the image inside the active section like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.bdt-active img').src = 'logo-2.png';
```

Comment: Thanks, and this does work in the console, however it's not firing on the page. This is because when the page loads the class "bdt-active" doesn't exist, it gets dynamically added when the page scrolls and the sticky header is active.

The general logic would be:

logo-1.png shows on page load,
If the page is scrolled the "btd-active" is present (by other javascript) to the <div>,
then do the querySelector img.src manipulation to logo-2.png,
otherwise retain logo-1.png

Comment: Yes, of course. But you're listening to the `onscroll` event to add/remove the `bdt-active` class, right? If so, after adding that class you can add that line to change the image src.